# TYPO3 MenuProcessor NULL output

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to generate main menu on my TYPO3 website, based on pages on website, like in this tutorial: [HERE](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/MainMenuCreation/Index.html), but my menu doesn't get rendered. This is the part in fluid partial, where I render my menu:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <f:debug inline="true">{mainnavigation}</f:debug>
            <f:for each="{mainnavigation}" as="menuItem">
                <li class="nav-item {f:if(condition: menuItem.active, then: 'active')}">
                    <a class="nav-link px-3 py-2" href="{menuItem.link}" target="{menuItem.target}"
                        title="{menuItem.title}">{menuItem.title}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </f:for>
        </ul>
```

And here is my TypoScript configuration for page:

```
page = PAGE

page {
   typeNum = 0

   // Part 1: Fluid template section
   10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   10 {
      templateName = TEXT
      templateName {    
          cObject = TEXT
          cObject {
            data = pagelayout
            required = 1
            case = ucfirst
            split {
              token = pagets__
              cObjNum = 1
              1.current = 1
            }
          }
      
          ifEmpty = Default
      }

      templateRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:website/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
      }
      
      partialRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:website/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
      }

      layoutRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:website/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
      }
      
      dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
           levels = 1
           includeSpacer = 1
           as = mainnavigation
        }
      }
   }
}
```

As you see from Fluid template, I try to debug my mainnavigation and I get NULL value. I have created 4 pages in backend with 7 subpages on one page. I must have missed something, but I don't see it.

Comment: I assume, the pages are not hidden?

Comment: No. and I also included arguments="{_all}" to my layout, where I call partial Menu.html. Now I get empty array for variable mainnavigation..